# Messages stop being read from MSMQ

Tags: msmq

I have a server which acts as an MSMQ "drop box" which sits between BizTalk and six client PCs.  Messages are written to the MSMQs on this server by BizTalk and read by the client PC applications.  There are three different queues per client PC, each handling a different business transaction.  So a total of 18 queues on the MSMQ server.

The MSMQ server is running Win 2012 R2 and the Client PCs WinXP.  Direct addressing is used for the queue names and there is no authentication between the two untrusted domains.  The queues are non-transactional and recoverable.  A lot of research and testing went into getting all of this to work thanks to the many blogs!

Everything has been running fine for over a month now until the MSMQ server had to be rebooted.  After the reboot all of the client PCs were able to read their queues with the exception of two client PCs which are not reading messages from 1 or the 3 queues used by that client (so 16 queues all fine, 2 not).  The application is reporting that there is nothing to read on the queue.

Why, after the reboot of the MSMQ server do most of the messaging return to normal behaviour but 2 queues don't?

Comment: Are the Windows XP clients cloned or was MSMQ manually installed on each?

Comment: They are cloned from an SOE image.

Comment: John,  Sorry for not responding earlier but we are deploying into a corporate network and so making changes takes time.  We regenerated the MQID on each XP client and then on Tuesday evening rebooted the central server.  All 6 queues on all clients "recovered" fine and messages have been flowing since.  So I'm pretty confident we have this one solved.  We'll resume client deployments next week (750+ in total).  Thanks for your help, it really got us out of a hole.

Answer (score 1):

MSMQ installations need to have a unique QMID to allow machines to differentiate between themselves. Cloning breaks MSMQ. [See blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnbreakwell/archive/2007/02/06/msmq-prefers-to-be-unique.aspx).